# Override a constraint in an external jar

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have an Address library (internal) that I am using, which contains an Address class. The Address class already contains a @NotEmpty validation on the postalCode.

In my app I need to expand the constraints to be on city and state/province as well. 
I've seen suggestions on configuring it through xml, and then rebuilding the validation factory, as well as adding a custom constraint.

I tried the latter with no avail (@StrictAddress is my custom constraint):

```
public addressDTO saveAddress(@StrictAddress @RequestBody Address address)
```

with the isValid method of the validator like so:

```
public boolean isValid(Address address, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext)
{
    if (null == address.getStreet() || address.getStreet().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (null == address.getCity() || address.getCity().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (null == address.getStateProv() || address.getStateProv().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (null == address.getPostalCode() || address.getPostalCode().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (null == address.getCountry() || address.getCountry().trim().isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When running with this setup, I get no indication that validation was ever done (it should have failed). When I replace the @StrictAddress with the standard @Valid, then I get the original validation error on the postalCode.

What am I missing? And is this a good way to approach this?

Comment: You could use your own domain model and then map it to the 3rd party library. Then you would not have the problem with overriding constraints. But then you have to deal with the mapping. BTW: have a look at Strings.isEmptyOrNull(String) (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html) instead of null and empty checking.

Comment: What framework do you use? And which version of Bean Validation?

Comment: I am using Spring Framework 4.0.0.RELEASE and using Hibernate-Validator 4.2.0.Final.